# Convert framenumber to timestamp and plot correctly on x-axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time

I am plotting some data with matplotlib. On the x-axis, I have the frame number of a video, which I convert to timestamps. However, I am getting an extra '01' in there, which I don't want. The format should be frame number --> hh:mm. The video is 25 frames per second, so for example frame number 37500 should be 00:25. But instead, I get '01 00:25' on the x-axis legend. How can I get rid of the first part?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

 
x = np.arange(0, 1600)
t = pd.to_datetime(x, 
                    unit='s')      
t_list = t.to_list()

y = np.ones(1600)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(t, y,
         linewidth=0.5,
         color='C0')

plt.xlabel('Time (hh:mm)')

plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.xlim(t_list[0], t_list[-1])
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
# fig.autofmt_xdate() # auto format
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `t = pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').dt.time`?

Comment: This results in an AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: In that case, try `t = pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').time`. It's different for Series and Datetimeindex.